# Python creat payment and send it with private key

Tags: python, payments

I am thinking/trying to create payment system. Just to learn more about crypto.
I would like to generate public and private key. And send(broadcast) payment into the eth network using python. 
How should I do it?
Btw. Thanks for any help and info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a few tools you can use, here are the links to help you get started:

Web3Py:

- https://github.com/ethereum/web3.py

Pyethereum:

- https://github.com/ethereum/pyethereum

Main Ethereum Client (geth, can be plugged into via web3py):

- https://geth.ethereum.org/downloads/

Answer (score 1):

I do something similar, but only need to use the Ethereum sparingly.  so instead of learning these subpar python tools for interacting with the network, I just use javascript and then submit my javascript file in python with arguments passed.

Here's the basic program to call my 'Details.js' file in python:

```
from Naked.toolshed.shell import execute_js

def ex(file_path, arguments=""):
    try:
        if len(arguments) > 0:
            js_command = file_path + " " + arguments
        else:
            js_command = file_path
        return execute_js(js_command) # return result of execute() of node.js file
    except Exception as e:
        if DEBUG_FLAG:
             sys.stderr.write("Naked Framework Error: unable to run the shell command with the run_js() function (Naked.toolshed.shell.py).")
        raise e 
ex('Details.js',"0xc99CC3CeD3208A5637bdb52cD2aD03550A62F71C")
```

I like this way much better since its easier to find javascript examples of how to send Ether transactions.